# Openssl issue with python 3.8

Tags: python

I am trying to use a python package wptools. When I do I get this error:

```
import pycurl
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/c/.virtualenvs/j/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pycurl.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libssl.1.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/c/.virtualenvs/j/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pycurl.cpython-38-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

I have tried all kinds of things, such installing with brew install openssl. What is weird is when I open a terminal on my mac, which uses python 3.7.6, it works. But when I try it in a virtual env, which is 3.8.10, it does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried recreating the virtualenv after changing versions?

Comment: Yes I created a new virtualenv and installed there, still have the same problem. :(